# 6DOF camera: inverted yaw and roll when orientation changes

Tags: c#, camera, monogame

Whenever I change the orientation of the camera, yaw and roll become inverted (or correct); the strafing, movement and pitch do remain correct however.

Can you tell what is causing this and how to fix it ?

```
private Vector3 _cameraOrientation;
private Vector3 _cameraPosition;
private Matrix _matrixProjection;
private Matrix _matrixView;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    var state = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
    if (state.Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed ||
        Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        Exit();
    if (state.Buttons.Start == ButtonState.Pressed) _cameraPosition = _cameraOrientation = Vector3.Zero;

    var right = state.ThumbSticks.Right;
    var left = state.ThumbSticks.Left;

    // get position/orientation deltas from gamepad
    var position = new Vector3
    {
        X = left.X,
        Y = state.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed ? -1 : state.Buttons.Y == ButtonState.Pressed ? 1 : 0,
        Z = -left.Y,
    };
    var orientation = new Vector3
    {
        X = -right.Y,
        Y = -right.X,
        Z = state.Buttons.X == ButtonState.Pressed ? -1 : state.Buttons.B == ButtonState.Pressed ? 1 : 0
    };

    // update position according orientation
    _cameraOrientation += orientation;
    var cameraReference = Vector3.Forward;
    var cameraRotation =
        Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.WrapAngle(MathHelper.ToRadians(_cameraOrientation.X))) *
        Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.WrapAngle(MathHelper.ToRadians(_cameraOrientation.Y))) *
        Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.WrapAngle(MathHelper.ToRadians(_cameraOrientation.Z)));
    _cameraPosition += Vector3.Transform(position, cameraRotation);

    // update matrices
    var cameraPosition = _cameraPosition;
    var cameraTransformedReference = Vector3.Transform(cameraReference, cameraRotation);
    var cameraTarget = cameraPosition + cameraTransformedReference;
    var cameraUpVector = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Up, cameraRotation); // Vector3.Up;
    _matrixView = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, cameraUpVector);
    _matrixProjection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45),
        _graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.01f, 100000f);

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: I've just started going through the code. If you keep this algorithm, I'd recommend that you rename variables like `position` to `velocity`, `positionDelta`, or anything else that is more indicative of their purposes.

Comment: Also, you can accumulate just the rotation, first, and then determine the correct movement direction from `cameraRotation`; i.e. `cameraRotation.Forward`, `cameraRotation.Left`. Both of the directions returned are relative to the stored rotation, not "the world". So, `If (left.X != 0) _cameraPosition += cameraRotation.Right * left.X;`

Comment: Unconfirmed, but I think your problem may be order-of-operations; i.e. `Matrix.CreateRotationX` creates "pitch". You are applying X, then Y, then Z which is Pitch, then Yaw, then Roll. Each of the matrices you are creating is relative to world-space ("Up" is +Y). When you pitch the camera past 90 degrees (first), camera-space "Up" becomes world-space "Down".

Comment: (Sorry Mods; I'll compile all of my comments into an answer after a little feedback from the OP) -- You are also starting your camera at `Vector3.Forward`, looking toward (0,0); that means that, initially, `Camera.Forward` is `Vector3.Backward`. Positive rotations are clock-wise, relative to the axis being twisted which is why starting at `Vector3.Forward` is an intuitive solution. The other and, more common, intuitive solution is starting at `Vector3.Backward`, looking toward (0,0), and inverting your sticks' pitch values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer works properly : [beginner: camera quaternion rotation (space sim)](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/26070/682449.aspx)